# Change TabBar Color after app has loaded

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

If I put code in my AppDelegate's DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions function, I am easily able to change the Tab Bar's color, but if I call a function with the same code in a ViewController, then it does not change. How can I get it to change after pressing a button in a view controller for example?

Here is the code in the DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions function:

```
 UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
 UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `appearance` proxy sets the attributes for any new control created afterwards. It doesn't change any existing related control.

If you wish to set the attributes of a specific, existing instance, set the attributes directly on the control without using the `appearance` proxy.

```
someTabBar.tintColor = UIColor.purple
someTabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orange
```

Comment: I'd also add (based on the OP) that the code needs to probably be in viewWillAppear.